# php flattening nested array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, php-5.5

I have an array like this

$array:

```
{    name   : xyz
     version  : Array[2]
     {
         0 : Array[2]
         {
             id : 1
             batch : 1
         }
         1 : Array[2]
         {
             id : 2
             batch : 2
         } 
     }
}
```

How can I create an array like this:

```
$results[] = 
name:xyz, version:0, id:1, batch:1
name:xyz, version:1, id:2, batch:2
```

I want an array where the common fields are repeated.

Comment: That isn't an array in PHP format. Can you provide that?

Comment: Array[2]
{
   name = xyz
   array[2]
   {
 version = 0
  array[2]
  {
   id     = 1
                        batch  = 1
  }
  {
   id      = 2
     batch   = 2
  }
 version = 1
  array[1]
  {
   id      = 3
                        batch   = 3
  } 
  }

}


result = { name=>xyz,  version = 0, id = 1, batch = 1}
  { name=>xyz,  version = 0, id = 2, batch = 2}
  { name=>xyz,  version = 1, id = 3, batch = 3}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
$results = array();
$results[] = array('name' => 'xyz', 'version' => 0, 'id' => 1, 'batch' => 1);
$results[] = array('name' => 'xyz', 'version' => 1, 'id' => 1, 'batch' => 1);
```

Then access the first row by $results[0]['name']
Or second row by $results[1]['name']

**EDIT**

To convert from $array to $results, I have to assume your $array looks like this.

```
$array = 
array('name'    => 'xyz', 
      'version' => array(
                         0 => array(
                                    'id' => 1, 
                                    'batch' => 1
                                    ),
                         1 => array(
                                    'id' => 2, 
                                    'batch' => 2
                                    )
                         )
      );
```

then

```
$results = array();
$name = $array['name'];
foreach($array['version'] as $version => $idandbatch)
{
    $results[] = array('name' => $name,
                       'version' => $version,
                       'id' => $idandbatch['id'],
                       'batch' => $idandbatch['batch']);
}
```

You can access the array

```
foreach($results as $values)
{
    echo $values['name'];
    echo $values['version'];
    echo $values['id'];
    echo $values['batch'];
}
```

Comment: My question is - how do you create results[] with each index having all the 4 values (name, verison, id, batch)?

Comment: In my example you can. To access the four indexes in the first row: $results[0]['name'], $results[0]['version'], $results[0]['id'], $results[0]['batch'].
If you want to traverse each row, use:
foreach($results as $value){ $value['name']; $value['version']; $value['id']; $value['batch']; }

Comment: No.. My question is not how you trace the results[] array.  My questions how do you create results[] array from the given array $array. Once you have results[] array, we can traverse as you mentioned. BUT MY QUESTION is HOW DO YOU CREATE RESULTS[] FROM $array.